# Apache FastCGI server connection failure

Tags: apache, debian, fastcgi, php

I have a virtual machine base box for Debian wheezy that I've been using with [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) for the last few months without any issues, however yesterday when I brought up a new machine and updated/upgraded packages I started getting a FastCGI server connection failure error:

```
[Wed Jun 04 14:39:03 2014] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] (13)Permission denied: FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/vagrant/php5-fcgi": connect() failed
[Wed Jun 04 14:39:03 2014] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/vagrant/php5-fcgi"
```

I am able to resolve the issue temporarily by manually touching and chmodding `/tmp/php5-fpm-vagrant.sock`, but my question is why did it start happening all of a sudden?

Personal preferences aside, is there anything functionally wrong with my configuration?:

In my apache sites available I have a file called `000php` containing:

`FastCgiExternalServer /vagrant/php5-fcgi -socket /tmp/php5-fpm-vagrant.sock -pass-header Authorization`

Since apache loads sites alphabetically, this always gets loaded first, then I have another file called `vagrant` that contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8080>
   DocumentRoot /vagrant/public_html/
   ServerName vagrant.localhost

   <Directory /vagrant/>
      AllowOverride all
   </Directory>

   AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
   Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
   Alias /php5-fcgi /vagrant/php5-fcgi

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vagrant_error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vagrant_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and a php fpm pool config called `vagrant.conf` that looks like this:

```
[vagrant]
listen = /tmp/php5-fpm-vagrant.sock

listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

user = vagrant
group = vagrant

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 50
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer, this was caused by https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67060

The fix was to add the following lines to my `vagrant.conf` php fpm configuration file and restart php fpm, a reload was not enough

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```