# Nginx as reverse proxy for Apache not working - serving static file

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I configured a vps server with nginx, php-fpm and apache on it.

**Usual web sites** with .html extension **are serverd** as static web pages like **normal**, but when I try to use .php page which dynamically generate content I see only pure html code like Nginx is serving .txt file.

Nginx listens on 80, Apache on 8080.

Mods disabled:
   `mod_proxy, mod_actions`

Nginx server block configuration:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://IP:8080;
    }
}
```

Apache virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Nginx & Apache both work under %username%, using %username% as group too.

Code seems to be correct, but the problem is when I load webpage example.com/index.php it is loaded like a .txt file with pure html code instead of normal .php page.

Same with info.php with usual `"<?php phpinfo(); ?>"`

**I see code but not real** info **page**.

Comment: I found answers to my problem in this threads:
[link](http://askubuntu.com/a/391642)
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24145983/5658700)
[link](http://askubuntu.com/a/526741)
The solution was to configure /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf with -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock instead of -host 127.0.0.1:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure either `nginx` or Apache to send the file to the php interpreter.

See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) to use `nginx` and `php-fpm` with the `fastcgi_pass` directive.

See [this document](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) to use Apache and `mod_php`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I appreciate it, but I managed to find answers myself.